# Custom meta boxes not saving

Tags: custom-field, customization, metabox

I am trying to create a custom meta box with 12 fields. There are 3 groups of 4 fields, so I am using a for loop to create them to save on typing etc.

For some reason I can't seem to get them to save. I am not sure if my coding is correct? I checked to see if they were being saved by doing a var dump of `var_dump($linktext[1]);` to see if it was being saved and that returned null.

This is the call back for the add metabox to output the fields in the back end in the meta box:

```
function home_callout_meta_box_cb($post) {
    global $post;
    wp_nonce_field('home_callout_nonce', 'home_callout_meta_box_nonce');
    $values = get_post_custom($post->ID);

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {

        $imagefield1[$i] = isset($values['imagefields'][$i]) ? esc_attr($values['imagefields'][$i]['image1'][0]): '';
        $imagefield2[$i] = isset($values['imagefields'][$i]) ? esc_attr($values['imagefields'][$i]['image2'][0]): '';

        $linktext[$i] = isset($values['linktext'][$i]) ? esc_attr($values['linktext'][$i][0]): '';
        $link[$i] = isset($values['link'][$i]) ? esc_attr($values['link'][$i][0]): '';


        echo '<p><strong>Call out box ' . $i .' image 1</strong></p>';
        echo '<div>';
        echo '<input type="text" id="imagefields'. [$i] . '[image1]" name="imagefields' . [$i] . '[image1]" class="upload-url image_url" readonly="readonly" value="' . $imagefield1[$i] .'" />';
        echo '<input id="st_upload_button" class="st_upload_button button-secondary upload_image" type="button" name="upload_button" value="Upload" />';
        echo '</div>';

        echo '<p><strong>Call out box ' . $i .' image 2</strong></p>';
        echo '<div>';
        echo '<input type="text" id="imagefields' . [$i] . '[image2]" name="imagefields' . [$i] . '][image2]" class="upload-url image_url" readonly="readonly" value="' . $imagefield2[$i] .'" />';
        echo '<input id="st_upload_button" class="st_upload_button button-secondary upload_image" type="button" name="upload_button" value="Upload" />';
        echo '</div>';

        echo '<p><strong>Call out box ' . $i .' link text</strong></p>';
        echo '<input type="text" id="linktext' . [$i] . '" name="linktext' . [$i] . '" value="' . $linktext[$i] . '" />';

        echo '<p><strong>Call out box ' . $i .' link</strong></p>';
        echo '<input type="text" id="link' . [$i] . '" name="link' . [$i] . '" value="' . $link[$i] . '" />';

    }
}
```

and this is my save function:

```
function home_callout_save($post_id) {
    if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return;
    if(!isset($_POST['home_callout_meta_box_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['home_callout_meta_box_nonce'], 'home_callout_nonce')) return;
    if(!current_user_can('edit_pages')) return;

    if(isset($_POST['imagefields'])) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'imagefields', $_POST['imagefields']);   
    }

    if(isset($_POST['linktext'])) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'linktext', $_POST['linktext']);
    }
    if(isset($_POST['link'])) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'link', $_POST['link']);
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'home_callout_save');
```

I think I've been staring at this same code for so long I think it might be a small mistake I've made and can't seem to see it.

Thanks for reading and any help is very much appreciated.

**Edit:**

Here is what I get from a vardump of `$values['linktext']`:

string(75) "a:3:{i:1;s:11:"link text 1";i:2;s:11:"Link 2 text";i:3;s:11:"Link 3 text";}"

I cant see how to put that returned value into the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the $_POST array in a wrong way. This is not possible:

```
$_POST['imagefields[' . $i . '][image2]']
```

Correct way would be:

```
$_POST['imagefields'][$i]['image2'];
```

*(You have the same mistake when accessing the `$values` array.)*

Also you are supposed to give the complete array to the `update_post_meta()` function instead of saving each value seperately:

```
 if(isset($_POST['imagefields'])) {
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'imagefields', $_POST['imagefields']);
}
```

****EDIT****

You can see if the values where saved to post_meta correctly using this code:

```
$values = get_post_custom($post->ID);
var_dump($values);
```

To fix the $values part you need to change all occurences of:

```
$values['imagefields[' . $i . '][image1]']
```

To:

```
$values['imagefields'][$i]['image1']
```

Comment: Oh okay thanks for answering. I'm not able to test out but actually makes a lot of sense. I will try it out tonight and accept as soon. Thank you

Comment: Hi thanks for responding again. I think it is now saving but i cant get the values to appear in the text boxes afterwards. could you just clarify how to fix my mistake on the $values part please. So i am var dumping var_dump($values['imagefields']); and i can see the full array if i add [0] i can get the first one in the array. but if i add [$i] it throws null?

Comment: @user720414 I updated my answer. I hope you can make it work now.

Comment: Hi thanks again for updating. I am away from my pc now but will try it tomorrow. Also does image2 need to be in quotes when I do the post

Comment: Generally everything that is a string needs to be in quotes and everything that is a variable (starting with $) should not be in quotes. So you are right and 'image2' should be in quotes. I edited this now.

Comment: Hi, Ive updated my code that i am using and when i do a var dump it only shows one object in the array not 3? i also cant seem to show the values that are stored back in them fields

Comment: Hi, I've accepted you answer as you did actually solve my issue with the values not being saved. If you dont mind could you help me get the values to be displayed back into the fields? I would really appreciate it